# Python: Find element in the list which has frequency = 2

Tags: python

Let's say I have a list:

Input:
ids = [123, 456, 123]

I need to find the element whose frequency is 2.

Output:
123

Best way to do this in python?

Comment: @njzk2 wtf? every second element vs frequency of 2 is not quite the same thing...

Comment: frequency, period, same difference

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter
counter = Counter(ids)
[k for k,v in counter.items() if v == 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a `set` and count each item (or make a `Counter` or `defaultdict`), then find which one has a count of 2.

```
ids = [123, 456, 123]
freq = 2
set_ids = set(ids)
counts = {item:ids.count(item) for item in set_ids}
for item in counts:
    if counts[item] == freq:
        print(item)
```

```
import collections
ids = [123, 456, 123]
freq = 2
counted_ids = collections.Counter(ids)
for item in counted_ids:
    if counted_ids[item] == freq:
        print(item)
```

```
import collections
ids = [123, 456, 123]
freq = 2
counts = collections.defaultdict(int)
for item in ids:
    counts[item] += 1
for item in counts:
    if counts[item] == freq:
        print(item)
```

Comment: @LucasCrawford - I wasn't golfing. Maybe if I could type three times faster this answer would be worth something.

Answer (score 0):

This is can be done also with a built-in method, [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=filter#filter) to *filter* out only those elements who shall meet your requirement, but better do it on a set rather than list to not repeat it for the same element:

```
>>> ids = [123, 456, 123]
>>> s = set(ids)
>>> filter(lambda x:ids.count(x)==2, s)
>>> list(filter(lambda x:ids.count(x)==2, s)) #If Python3
[123]
```